# What is CORS in npm, can putty be used for development of a web application?

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, express, cors

I am working/learning on web application that has following dependencies:

1. Express.js + Node.js
2. MySQL
3. Angular 4
4. PM2 (Process manager)

Libs used on the backend:

1. express
2. body-parser
3. jsonwebtoken
4. bcrypt-nodejs
5. socketio-jwt
6. async.js
7. request
8. deep-diff
9. socket.io
10. cors
11. mysql

Libs used for the front end

1. angular2-jwt
2. socket.io-client
3. angular-2-dropdown-multiselect
4. angular2-tree-component

I wanted to know about the usage of CORS, putty for the development in detail for this app.

Comment: One question per question please. CORS? Use your favorite search engine to look for `node express cors` and you'll get something useful.

Comment: actually i did, but i needed some specific explanation, the application i am working on is based on server & client stack app, I am new to this concept, being student, trying to explore

Comment: also i didn't got perfect explanation of role of putty client for web development, is it really required to setup the connection?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS or Cross-Origin Resource Sharing is a spec that appeared for security reason :

Your browser won't allow you to do http request to another domain except if your server-app return specifics headers (they start with `Access-Control-Allow`).

The npm cors module allow you to add those headers field in an easier way : `app.use(cors())`

Putty is a ssh client its permit you to connect to a remote server using ssh protocol (usually you use it to configure  your server or run your app on your server).The server need to host an ssh-server like openSSH (nativ on linux).

Comment: so is there any relation between cors and putty to login into a web application?

Comment: I am having problem with the output even if the my sql database is connected

Comment: so is there any relation between putty and cors for logging into web application even if the mysql workbench is connected & running?

Comment: No there is not, cors is just a "process" to allow your client-app to request your server-app (and i'm talking about applications), putty is for managing a remote server (a physical or virtual machine, like a computer). if you want some help on debbuging you should edit your question to provide some code, explain what you tired and the errors you get

Comment: Or you should just create another question to not get this one too messy (but don't forget questions here are essentially for debug purpose, and not really to give tips/advice - opinion's related question)